# Bash: how to add subdirs to the PATH

Tags: bash, path

In `.bashrc` I have added a dir where I put some scripts. Is that possible - to add all its subdir automatically - so that I would not have to add them one-by-one manually? (and wouldn't have to visit `.bashrc` every time I'll make a dir there)

**Edit**:

Using Laurent Legrand's solution, that's what I'm using now:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/NAMD_2.7_Linux-x86_64:/usr/local/share/jmol-12.0.31:/usr/local/share/NAMD_2.7_Linux-x86_64_orig:/usr/local/share/sage-4.6.2:/opt/mongoDB/bin

PATH=$PATH:$(find ~/Study/geek/scripts -type d -printf "%p:")
```

this adds the dir and its sub dirs.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a final colon in `PATH` variable using the @LaurentLegrand solution?

Comment: I have it - but it works this way - files in the sub dirs are known to my system.

Comment: Sure it works but you aren't supposed to have and ending colon in your `PATH` variable. Think about the default `PATH` variable in your out of the box Linux OS. Here's mine for root user: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that should work

```
 PATH=$PATH:$(find your_dir -type d -printf "%p:")
```

Comment: Nice one but you will have a final colon in PATH variable. Is that really what you want?   
Here's a possible fix usung sed: `PATH=$PATH:$(find your_dir -type d -printf "%p:" | sed -e 's/:$//g')`  
which will remove the last colon.

Answer (score 2):

in your .bashrc suppose that all your scripts are under ~/bin

```
maindir=~/bin
for subdir in `tree -dfi $maindir`
do
    PATH=$PATH:$subdir
done
export $PATH
```

can do the trick ...

Comment: I would add a file test there: `if [ -d "$maindir/$subdir" ] ; then PATH="$PATH:$maindir/$subdir"; fi`

Comment: thanks mkb i replace ls by tree with -d options that lists only directories

Comment: Is tree typically installed by default? Neither of my two most convenient machines has it.

Comment: Don't know for every distribution, but MAC and Debian Base hasn't since it's not consider as a "base" package. But this is a very handy tool for all day use.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best practice to add executables from `/opt` directory to the path:

```
for subdir in $(find /opt -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d); do
  PATH="$subdir/bin:$PATH"
done
export $PATH
```

As all needed executables should be in `/opt/*/bin`, we are avoiding subdirs that are beyond `/opt/*` using `-maxdepth 1` and the `/opt` dir itself with `-mindepth 1`. *Also note that we added `/bin` to the end of each dir.*

Same can be applied in your case with scripts. If you need more depth, just modify value of `-maxdepth` or remove it completely for infinite levels (same applies for `-mindepth` if main script path shoud be included). **Just beware of ambiguity if same script name can be found in multiple subdirectory levels.**

So, in your case you may just use:

```
for subdir in $(find $HOME/path/to/scripts -type d); do
  PATH="$subdir:$PATH"
done
export $PATH
```